# What was the language Klaatu spoke in based on?

Tags: the-day-the-earth-stood-still

I recall reading years ago that a Professor of Linguistics (?Harvard) was consulted to develop the language that Klaatu spoke in "The Day the Earth Stood Still". I vaguely recall there may have been some overtones of Finnish in its inception.  I have searched the web without any success.  Does anyone have any reference on this?

N.B. I am not seeking after the "Klaatu barada nikto" history.  I have found information on that on the web.  I am asking for the basis of the totality of the language.

Comment: [The screenwriter's imagination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still#Klaatu_barada_nikto) apparently and not a professor of linguistics. There are references and further links provided on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: See [The Language of Klaatu](https://web.archive.org/web/20040628163125/http://www.dreamerwww.com/fanfilm/fanfilm2.htm) Linguistic Analysis, purportedly a Fantastic Films article from April 1978 by Tauna Le Marbe, showing some semblance of meaning as a mixture of Latin, French and mangled English which likely says the screenwriter Edmund North had a somewhat classical education (which wouldn't have been as unusual at the beginning of the 1950's. Unable to trace the article author for linguistic credentials. There are five bits of the language used in the film.